# I am trying to download the first 10 videos from a YouTube playlist. However, it keeps downloading more than 10

Tags: python, pytube

Pretty much the title. This is my code for what I am trying to do.

```
from pytube import Playlist
from youtube_transcript_api import YouTubeTranscriptApi

link = "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLI1yx5Z0Lrv77D_g1tvF9u3FVqnrNbCRL"
playlist = Playlist(link)

maxVideos = 10
start = 0

while start < maxVideos:
    for video in playlist.videos:
        start = start + 1
        try:
            print("Attempting to Download Video")
            video.streams.first().download()
            print("Done Downloading")
        except:
            print("Video age restricted.\n Downloading Next Video")
```

I tried a while loop as you can see over here. I also tried to make a new playlist where it was just the first 10 videos like this:

```
playlist = Playlist(link)
newPlaylist = playlist.video_urls[:10]

for video in newPlaylist.videos:
```

But I get an AttributeError saying that 'list' has no attribute 'videos'

I know I can just get the links for first 10 videos from the playlist that download but I want to minimize the number of lines that I have so it can be more efficient.

Comment: The second attempt should have been `newPlaylist.videos[:10]`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thank you! I tried that and it worked, the only issue is that one of the first 10 was age restricted so I ended up downloading 9 videos. I managed to get the correct output thanks to one of the other answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
from pytube import Playlist
from youtube_transcript_api import YouTubeTranscriptApi

link = "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLI1yx5Z0Lrv77D_g1tvF9u3FVqnrNbCRL"
playlist = Playlist(link)

maxVideos = 10
start = 0

for video in playlist.videos:
    start = start + 1
    if(start<=maxVideos):
      try:
          print("Attempting to Download Video")
          video.streams.first().download()
          print("Done Downloading")
      except:
          print("Video age restricted.\n Downloading Next Video")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your looping code doesn't do quite what you are expecting. Although you are checking if `start < max_videos` you only do this after a full loop through the list if videos. Try instead:

```
from pytube import Playlist
from youtube_transcript_api import YouTubeTranscriptApi

link = "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLI1yx5Z0Lrv77D_g1tvF9u3FVqnrNbCRL"
playlist = Playlist(link)

maxVideos = 10
downloaded = 0
for video in playlist.videos:
    if downloaded >= max_videos:
        break
    try:
        print("Attempting to Download Video")
        video.streams.first().download()
        print("Done Downloading")
    except:
        print("Video age restricted.\n Downloading Next Video")
    downloaded += 1
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked, I just had to change it from >= to > because it updated even if the video was age restricted.

Comment: Your welcome. Your solution to the age restriction issue only works if exactly 1 video is age restricted. To fully solve the problem, you could move the `downloaded += 1` line into an `else` clause of the `try ... except` (see [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp))